# Create Insert Trigger PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have write a PL/SQL insert trigger but it doesn't compile properly but I don't see the problem.

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_NEWROW
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE OF STATUS_ID ON application FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO APPLICATION_HISTORY
      (APPLICATION_ID, STATUS_ID, DATE_OF_CHANGE)
    VALUES
      (1, 1, SYSDATE)  
END;
```

Comment: You are missing an `;` after your SQL statement

Answer (score 3):

Try this: You missed a ';' at the end of Insert statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_NEWROW
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF STATUS_ID
    ON APPLICATION
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
          APPLICATION_HISTORY ( APPLICATION_ID,
                            STATUS_ID,
                            DATE_OF_CHANGE )
    VALUES
          ( 1,
            1,
            SYSDATE );
END;
/
```